# How to load a JSON tableView and save data even on dismiss?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I currently have a button that opens a TableViewController and loads the data using JSON like the following:

```
private func JSON() {
    print(facility)
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example/example/example"),
        let sample = value1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "example1=\(example)".data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            self.JStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode([exampleStruct].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Then after I am done looking at the tableview I close it by doing:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

using a BarButtonItem.

The issue is every time the UIView opens it takes some time to load the data. Is there anyway to have the tableView load just once and when dismissed and re-opened just have the same data show that was already loaded before?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to store the data locally. Either use a local database or a plain text file to store the data. When you open the page check whether data is already present. If it is already present load it, and call the API in background silently to update the existing data. If data is not saved, call the API, load the data and save it locally.

```
func getFileURL() -> URL {
    let fileName = "CacheData"
    let documentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = documentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("json")
    return fileURL
}

func createFile(data: Data) {
    let fileURL = getFileURL()
    do {
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func loadData() -> Data? {
    let fileURL = getFileURL()
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return data
    } catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

In your viewDidLoad method do something like:

```
let fileURL = getFileURL()
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
   if let data = loadData() {
      do {
          self.JStruct = try 
      JSONDecoder().decode([exampleStruct].self,from:data)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
      } catch {
          print(error)
      }
   }
}
JSON()
```

And call the createFile when you get data from the API. You may need to write the file and load the file using a background queue to avoid overloading and freezing of your main thread.

Comment: Can you please show how this can done? I would really appreciate it

Comment: @HenryPinston The database implementation is too broad, I'll try to add the file based implementation.

Comment: Ok that is fine

Comment: I  keep getting the error **Value of optional type  'Data?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Data'** on line `self.JStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode([exampleStruct].self,from:data)`

Comment: @HenryPinston You need to unwrap that, updated the answer

Comment: Now after `self.JStruct = try` I get **Errors thrown from here are not handled**

Comment: A better practice is to return non-optional `Data`from `loadData()` and make the method `throw`. Then put it into the `do` block together with `JSONDecoder()`

Comment: @HenryPinston To solve *Errors .. are not handled* just wrap the `try` line in a `do - catch` block like in your question

Comment: Ok so now I have changed `if let data = loadData() {` to `guard let data = loadData() else { return }` as well as do and catch

Comment: But the file is still not being created with the JSON data and the information is still being pulled from JSON() as before

Comment: @vadian Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @HenryPinston Print the url.path and check whether file is being created or not. Also debug whether data is loaded or not. Turnoff the network and check data is being loaded or not

Comment: The url is printing and .json file does exist, but I have noticed that it still takes a few seconds to load, shouldn't it load as fast as the view controller opens since it is local?

Comment: Actually when removing JSON() nothing loads, so it is creating the file but not reading the info from it

Comment: @vadian I have further investigated the issue, the .json file is being created and is putting it under the apps Documents but when downloading the containers in Xcode, the file is not there. Do you mind explaining how this could be happening